# Writing unit tests for open systems such as Email or SMS senders in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

i would like to write unit tests for Email and SMS senders that i have in my project, ofcourse since they are open systems i can't test their functionalities from end to end. So i'm looking for a smart way test them.

Below is the code i am using to send email and SMS:

Email:

```
    public void Send(MailMessage msg)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailSetting.EmailUser
        , emailSetting.EmailPass);
        client.Send(msg);
    }
```

SMS :

```
   public void SendSMS( String toNumber, String message)
    {
         if (client != null)
            client.SendSmsMessage(smsSetting.SMS_Num, toNumber, message);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with that is that if you are really going for `unit-test`s then you'd want to `mock` the mail/sms client.

If you want to actual send emails (which will result in spam if they are ran overnight / during development cycle) then they don't classify as unit-tests, but integration tests.

As a mocking example:

```
 public class EmailThingy
 {
     private readonly IEmailClient _client;

     public EmailThingy(IEmailClient client)
     {
          _client = client;
     }

     public void Send()
     {
          // do stuff with client
     }
 }
```

In your unit test

```
    [Test]
    public void SendEmail()
    {
        var clientMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IEmailClient>();

        // define behaviour for clientmock

        var sut = new EmailThingy(clientMock);
        sut.SendMail();
    }
```

Comment: sounds like a good solution, i will have to read about mocks first, but can you give me an idea of what exactly will happen in the test method?

Comment: All your added business logic can be tested that way. The idea is that you mock that part that isn't part of you SuT (system under test). So, in your case, sending the actual email is not logic that you wrote. It's a framework that you use. If you call it correctly, it will just do whatever it's supposed to do (send emails). The additional logic is how **you** want mails to be sent, that is what you can validate using unit tests (it's a learning curve, just jump into the world of mocking and you'll get used to the concepts)

Comment: What will happen is that you set-up a "fake" object (the mock) and pass that to your SuT (`EmailThingy`). When you call `SendMail()` the SuT will interact with you mock object, as if it was the actual mail service. Your mock has predefined behaviour (i.e. it does whatever you tell it to do) and you can verify the code that you are actually interested in.

Comment: it helps if you accept the answer that solved your question for future references

Answer (score 1):

for sms 
Can be done in following ways.

Step 1: Navigate to your Web.Config file and add the following tags to it.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="E:\MailTest\"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Make sure the directory you have specified for pickup location must exist.

Step 2 : Now test your email sending functionality. I have used button_click to test this functionality with the following code.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("me@gmail.com", "me@yahoo.com","My Message Subject","This is a test message");
smtp.Send(message);
```

Output : It will create .eml files inside the folder with a randonly generated GUID name, which is the email that we can see after receiving it. For me it created a file like `c127d1d5-255d-4a5a-873c-409e23002eef.eml in E:\MailTest\ folder`

Comment: i am working on a console application actually, and i want to test the email without actually sending it..isn't that a little bit different than your case?

Comment: you can add app.config in your project and other assembly that you need and test this code

Comment: +1, but remember, this is now an *integration test*. Unit tests test classes and objects under *complete isolation*. So your solution depends on exactly what you are trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic for a dependency injection solution and mocking.

Write your code as though you could be using anyone of a number of SMS solutions.

Create an Interface say ISMS with a method say Send(recipient, message);

Then implement it in your code that directly calls the sms stuff.

Them when you hahve something that need sms functionality, you instantiate the implementation you want to use and pass it to that code. Now it doesn't care what does the SMS and how.

Have a look at the service locator pattern for a good way to do this.

When it comes to unit testing, you can then create a mock class that implements the interface and inject that. It doesn't send an sms, it might check that recipient and message are valid though, but it doesn't spam your entire team with test data.

Testing that your sms implementation work then done separately, as it doesn't care why , when or what mesage is being sent.

If you wanted to do an end to end test, then that would be an integration test not a unit test, as there's much more than a unit involved.